# Rails 4 One query for select users from workspace with specific role (has_many through)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I have following models:

```
class Workspace < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  has_many :workspaces_memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :workspaces_memberships
  has_many :roles, :through => :workspaces_memberships
...
end

class WorkspacesMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :workspace, touch: true
  belongs_to :role
...
end
```

I want to select `all users` from `workspace`, who have role `admin` (`role_id 1`, but it would be brilliant to search it by name in `Role` model) in one query (in `WorkspacesMembership` model I have `user_id`, `workspace_id`, `role_id`).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you update database Schema?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but I wouldn't like to do it for one query.

Comment: You want users, right? Or I misunderstood your question? Because, the answers I see seems to be fetching workspaces which have membership of role admin.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Workspace.joins(:roles).where('roles.name = ?', "admin")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this :

```
Workspace.joins(:roles).merge(Role.where(:name=>"admin"))
```

joins and includes used with merge are very powerful for complex requests.

Check if you want an INNER JOIN (joins) or a LEFT OUTER JOIN (includes).

EDIT : As pointed by Surya I misread the question.

Here is a query to get all admin users of workspace_instance :

```
workspace_instance.users.joins(:roles).merge(Role.where(:name=>"admin"))
```

It implies that User have `has_many :roles, :through => :workspaces_memberships`

Comment: There's a problem, `Workspace.joins(:roles)` raises an error, because both `Workspace` and `Role` model have attribute name.

Comment: Sure, here u are: `PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "name" is ambiguous`

Comment: How's this query going to fetch users by the way?

Comment: If you are you doing Role.where("name=admin") instead of the hash, you must do ("Roles.name = admin"). What is your query generating the error?